# How to compare shapes of two curves

Tags: geometry, shapes

I want to get the value of similarity of two shapes of curves.
[image]

Above image, you can see two curves. I have a points array of red curve(black points).And also have the vertex points of blue polygon line(dark green points).
Now I want to get a value which evaluate how similar two graphs.
Please help me,Geniuses.

Comment: Basic solution idea: Follow both curves with speed proportional to their total length and calculate at each time interval the distance. Sum up those distances. The smaller this sum is, the more similar.

Comment: Please define what similarity refers to in this particular case.

Comment: I just wanted to calculate some value that expresses how similar they are.

Comment: You might use the [Hausdorff Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)